# Old gen heap space overflow

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a very weird problem with GC in Java. I am running th following piece of code:

```
 while(some condition){
        //do a lot of work...
        logger.info("Generating resulting time series...");
        Collection<MetricTimeSeries> allSeries = manager.getTimeSeries();
        logger.info(String.format("Generated %,d time series! Storing in files now...", allSeries.size()));

        //for (MetricTimeSeries series : allSeries) {
           // just empty loop
        //}
 }
```

When I look into JConsole, at the restart of every loop iteration, my old gen heap space, if I manually force GC, takes a size of about 90 MB. If I uncomment the loop, like this

```
 while(some condition){
        //do a lot of work...
        logger.info("Generating resulting time series...");
        Collection<MetricTimeSeries> allSeries = manager.getTimeSeries();
        logger.info(String.format("Generated %,d time series! Storing in files now...", allSeries.size()));

        for (MetricTimeSeries series : allSeries) {
           // just empty loop
        }
 }
```

Even if I force it to refresh, it won't fall below 550MB. According to yourKit profiler, the TimeSeries objects are accessible via main thread's local var (the collection), just after the GC at the restart of a new iteration... And the collection is huge (250K time series.)... Wyy is this happening and how can I "fight" this (incorrect?) behaviour?

Comment: what does manager.getTimeSeries(); do? Also, what does its returned value iterator function do?

Comment: Itis building an ArrayList of all time series it knows of (there are underlying objects that in turn do the same, for all time series they manage). At the end, one big ArrayList is build and returned, and the iterator is just Standard java iterator for List

Comment: does it ever exit while(some condition)?
p.s. its real difficult trying to solve a problem which is a black box

Comment: whether it ends make no difference, If I set the allSereis to null, or simply do not iterate, the Heap space falls down to the correct value... WTF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're building a (large) `ArrayList` of time series, it will occupy the heap as long as it's referenced, and will get promoted to old if it stays long enough (or if the young generation is too small to actually hold it). I'm not sure how you're associating the information you're seeing in JConsole or Yourkit to a specific point in the program, but until the empty loop is optimized by several JIT passes, your `while` loop will take longer and keep the collection longer, which might explain the perceived difference while there's actually not a lot.

There's nothing incorrect about that behaviour. If you don't want to consume so much memory, you need to change your `Collection` so it's not an eagerly-filled `ArrayList`, but a lazy collection, more of a stream (if you've ever done XML processing, think DOM vs SAX) which gets evaluated as it's iterated. If you don't need the whole collection to be sorted, that's doable, especially since you seem to be saying that the collection is a concatenation of sub-collections returned by underlying objects.

If you can change your return type from `Collection` to `Iterable`, you could for example use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`FluentIterable.transformAndConcat()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#transformAndConcat%28com.google.common.base.Function%29) to transform the collection of underlying objects to a lazily-evaluated `Iterable` concatenation of their time series. Of course, the size of the collection is not directly available anymore (and if you try to get it independently of the iteration, you'll evaluate the lazy collection twice).

Answer (score 2):

Yup, the garbage collector can be mysterious.. but it beats managing your own memory ;)

Collections and Maps have a way of hanging onto references longer than you *might* like and thus preventing garbage collection when you might expect. As you noticed, setting the `allSeries` reference to `null` itself will ear mark it for garbage collection, and thus it's contents are up for grabs as well. Another way would be to call `allSeries.clear()`: this will unlink all it's `MetricTimeSeries` objects and they will be free for garbage collection.

Why does removing the loop get around this problem also? This is the more interesting question. I'm tempted to suggest the compiler is optimizing the reference to `allSeries`.. but you are still calling `allSeries.size()` so it can't *completely* optimize out the reference.

To muddy the waters, different compiles (and settings) behave differently and use different garbage collectors which themselves behave differently. It's tough to say exactly what's happening under the hood without more information.

Comment: Passing the collection to other method for processing does the trick as well.... WTF????

Comment: btw, substituting regular iterator, and calling iterator.remove, changes nothing